# Connecting SQLBase Server running on Virual Machine

Tags: sqlbase, guptateamdeveloper

I have a physical Window Server 2008 R2 machine running SQLBase 8.5 and I have no problem connecting to it. Recently I migrated this server to a virtual machine and the problem come up. Sometimes I am able to connect to the Server and sometimes not.

I can pin my Virtual Server but not able to connect to it through SQLTalk or any client application.
Is anyone having the same issue running SQLBase 8.5 on a Virtual Machine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check how many users connect at a time. SQLBase 8.5 have some limitation when maximum number of users/cilents exceedes.
2. Try to find whether the issue occurs when a large query is executed. If so then try to simplify it.
3. Check for blocking issues. Try to test its working when disabling Internet security applications\antivirus\Firewall for some time.
4. Check for port issues. Check the 'listenport' value of sql.ini file.
5. Check for SQLBaseConnection properties and cross check the parmeters like 'connection lifetime'.

Comment: The problem solve after I open the 2155 port on window firewall. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

SQLBase 8.5 was only ever certified up to Windows Server 2003, and is so old I'm amazed it runs at all.  You should be running at least SQLBase v12 if you're on Window Server 2008.
Here is a compatibility matrix: [SQLBase compatibility v6 to v12.2](https://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=Misc/WhitePapers_Docs/&file=OpenText_Gupta_SQLBase_Compatibility_Matrix.pdf)

So assuming your SQLBase instance is actually up and running at the time you can't connect, check the CLIENT side sql.ini , there will be an ip address e.g. [image: Client SQ.ini].

On the CLIENT at command prompt, run: ping -t (ipaddressofserver in CLIENT sql.ini)

Comment: The problem solve after I open the 2155 port on window firewall. Thanks a lot.